# python regular expression : match one of listed substrings

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I want to retrieve web site addresses that ended up by **.com** or **.fr** but not by .edu . Here is my attempt and obviously it does not work:

```
import re
text="www.cool.fr www.ham.edu www.stanford.com www.hack.ru"
re.findall(ur"\S+\.[com|fr]",text)
```

I guess it might exist something that I don't know about regexp in order to address this problem in an elegant way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex uses a *character class* `[...]` where `|` matches a literal `|` symbol, it is not an alternation operator. The `[com|fr]` class matches either `c`, `o`, `m`, `|`, `f` or `r` characters.

You need to use a group and make sure there is a word boundary after the com or fr:

```
import re
text="www.cool.fr www.ham.edu www.stanford.com www.hack.ru"
print(re.findall(r"\S+\.(?:com|fr)\b",text))
# => ['www.cool.fr', 'www.stanford.com']
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/lqH6sg)

The regex matches:

- `\S+\.` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols followed by a literal `.`
- `(?:com|fr)` - a non0-capturing group matching 2 alternatives: either `com` or `fr` that are followed by...
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Wow, so fats, so efficient. Thank you so much!